# Conditional Statement for null values using Eval

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to set up a conditional statement for a particular value so that if the value is contained within the data set, it will append m2/kw but when its not it doesn't. I initially had this, but obviously it was still adding the "m2/kw" even if the value wasn't present.

```
<%#Eval("powerOutput") + "m<sup>2</sup>/kW" %>
```

So I rewrote it, and it still doesn't work.

```
<%#Eval("powerOutput").ToString() == "" ?  
Eval("powerOutput") + "m<sup>2</sup>/kW" : "" %>
```

Edit

```
<% if (Eval("powerOutput") != null)
                                                                       { %>

                                                                     <%# 
Eval("powerOutput") + "m<sup>2</sup>/kW" %>

                                                                     <% } 
else { %>  <% } %>
```

I've now got to this, but I'm now getting an error with

> Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in 
>        the context of a databound control.

Comment: I think you should revert the condition to be  <%#Eval("powerOutput").ToString() != "" ?  
Eval("powerOutput") + "m<sup>2</sup>/kW" : "" %>

Comment: Nope, this hasnt worked! Thanks for trying to help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%#Eval("powerOutput") + "m<sup>2</sup>/kW" %>
```

Instead of the above, assuming (as the question isn't explicitly clear) you could do the below if you're treating `"powerOutput"` as a string and testing for `null`:

```
string s = "powerOutput";
if(string.isNullOrEmpty(s)){
    s += "m<sup>2</sup>/kW";
}
```